# How to change SharePoint default redirection after form submit action?

Tags: javascript, form, custom-actions, redirect, survey-list

I have created SP survey list. After creating questions need to redirect to my custom page instead of going to overview page.I have included the java script file.Is possible to change the redirection after form submitted ?.Is possible to get the form submitted action using JavaScript ?.

suggest some idea to redirecting to the custom page.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a hyperlink on a page to point to create new questions page. In that hyperlink append a query string param "source=overview_page_url". Example

```
Http://site/list/testlist/newform.aspx?source=http://site/pages/overview.aspx
```

The page will redirect to overview.aspx if save or cancel button is clicked on the newform.aspx